# Adding annotations to Plotly Scatter Map

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am having trouble adding annotations to my plotly scattergeo map. I am using a pandas dataframe as my datasource with columns Lat, Long, and the text is the index. My resulting annotations parameter nested under the layout parameter looks like:

```
[dict(x= d[1]['Lat'], y= d[1]['Long'], text= d[0]) for d in df.iterrows()]
```

Conversely, I can just use a single annotation using one row (or even hard-coding values for test purposes). It seems the x,y placement is using the chart grid instead of the map grid to place the annotation. Is there a parameter to fix that or do I need to adjust the chart grid itself? Thank you in advance.

Edit: Here is an example. I wanted the annotations to be beside each bubble by passing the Lat/Long coordinates as the x,y variables of the annotation.

[image: plotly map example]

Answer (score 1):

You can try something similar to [that](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/#text-font-as-an-array---styling-each-text-element):

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Scattergeo(
            lat=[45.5,43.4,49.13,51.1,53.34,45.24,44.64,48.25,49.89,50.45],
            lon=[-73.57,-79.24,-123.06,-114.1,-113.28,-75.43,-63.57,-123.21,-97.13,-104.6],
            marker={
                "color": ["#bebada","#fdb462","#fb8072","#d9d9d9","#bc80bd","#b3de69","#8dd3c7","#80b1d3","#fccde5","#ffffb3"],
                "line": {
                    "width": 1
                },
                "size": 10
            },
            mode="markers+text",
            name="",
            text=["Montreal","Toronto","Vancouver","Calgary","Edmonton","Ottawa","Halifax","Victoria","Winnepeg","Regina"],
            textfont={
                "color": ["#bebada","#fdb462","#fb8072","#d9d9d9","#bc80bd","#b3de69","#8dd3c7","#80b1d3","#fccde5","#ffffb3"],
                "family": ["Arial, sans-serif","Balto, sans-serif","Courier New, monospace","Droid Sans, sans-serif","Droid Serif, serif","Droid Sans Mono, sans-serif","Gravitas One, cursive","Old Standard TT, serif","Open Sans, sans-serif","PT Sans Narrow, sans-serif","Raleway, sans-serif","Times New Roman, Times, serif"],
                "size": [22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13]
            },
            textposition=["top center","middle left","top center","bottom center","top right","middle left","bottom right","bottom left","top right","top right"]
        )
    ],
    layout={
        "title": "Canadian cities",
        "geo": {
            "lataxis": {
                "range": [40, 70]
            },
            "lonaxis": {
                "range": [-130, -55]
            },
            "scope": "north america"
        }
    }
)

plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='Canadian Cities')
```

**OLD Answer:**

```
import pandas as pd

# initial position
lat = 47.8388
lon = 35.1396

# generate random coordinates
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat + np.random.normal(1,0.2,10),'lon': lon + np.random.normal(1,0.2,10)})
df = df.round(4)

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.4f}'.format
df['text'] = df.lat.astype(str) + ', ' + df.lon.astype(str)
print(df)

ax = df.plot(x='lat', y='lon', kind='scatter')

y_shift = (df.lon.max()-df.lon.min())/len(df)
[ax.annotate(tup[2], xy=tup[:2], xytext=(tup[0], tup[1]))
 for tup in df.itertuples(index=False)]

plt.show()
```

I put the coordinates as a text for annotations...

[image: Plot]

Comment: I was hoping to plot the annotations on a plotly map instead of a regular grid. Edited my question and added image to try and make it clearer.

Comment: @fishball, sorry i didn't notice that. Maybe you can provide some sample data set so those willing to help could give it a try (test it)?